# SNMP trap message custom parsing

Tags: javascript, regex

The below line is taken from SNMP trap message.

> 1.3.6.1.4.1.34527.5.2.1.1.0 = 26-09-2019 10:33:08 T1E1 Layer-2 Down- Port: 1

How can i get the "**Layer**" no. and "**Port**" no. from the above string. Expected values are

```
Layer = 2 and Port = 1
```

Is any javascript regex solution for this?

```
var str = "1.3.6.1.4.1.34527.5.2.1.1.0 = 26-09-2019 10:33:08 T1E1 Layer-2 Down- Port: 1";

function getPortNo(str)
{

}

function getLineNo(str)
{

}
```

Already i have done with "split()" function.

```
var portNo = str.split("Port: ")[1];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `Layer\D+(\d+).+Port\D+(\d+)`

It will work only if `Layer` is before `Port` in your string.

Explanation:

`\D+(\d+)` - match one or more of non digits, then match one or ore digits and store it inside capturing group.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/j4GPZN/1)